# Abel's Summation (memorizing the theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to intuitively remember and understand Abel's Summation by Parts (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts):

$$\sum_{k=m}^n f_k(g_{k+1}-g_k)=[f_{n+1}g_{n+1}-f_mg_m]-\sum_{k=m}^n g_{k+1}(f_{k+1}-f_k)$$

Are there any tips to understand and memorize this formula? I know it is the discrete analogue of Integration by Parts, but I am having problem with the subscripts (e.g. remembering whether it is $k+1$ vs $k$).

My current method is to memorize the form $\int f\,dg=[fg]-\int g\,df$, and then perform some guess and check to verify the subscripts. This probably reflects some lack of understanding of Abel's lemma on my part. (The only proof I know is the direct verification by expanding out everything).

Any more intuitive ways of understanding and remembering Abel's Summation by Parts?

Thanks. Any comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easier to remember:

$$\sum f\Delta g=fg-\sum {\rm E}g\Delta f\tag{1}$$

where $\Delta f(k)=f(k+1)-f(k)$ and ${\rm E}f(k)=f(k+1)$. Showing explicitly the variable of sum the above can be written as

$$\sum f(k)\Delta g(k)\delta k=f(k)g(k)-\sum {\rm E}g(k)\Delta f(k)\delta k\tag{2}$$

where $\delta k$ is similar to ${\rm d}x$ in infinitesimal calculus, it is used to show the variable that is "summed". The above formulas $(1)$ and $(2)$ have no limits, i.e. are indefinite sums, analogous to indefinite integrals of infinitesimal calculus.

This is the summation by parts for finite calculus. Taking limits in $(1)$ or $(2)$ must be done following this rule of finite calculus:

$$\sum_{k=a}^b f(k)=\sum\nolimits_a^{b+1} f(k)\delta k$$

Then notice that

$$f_{n+1}g_{n+1}-f_mg_m=f(k)g(k)\Big|_m^{n+1}$$

i.e. taking limits on $(2)$ we write

$$\sum\nolimits_a^{b+1} f(k)\Delta g(k)\delta k=f(k)g(k)\Big|_a^{b+1}-\sum\nolimits_a^{b+1} {\rm E}g(k)\Delta f(k)\delta k$$

what is equivalent to write

$$\sum_{k=a}^{b} f(k)\Delta g(k)=f(k)g(k)\Big|_a^{b+1}-\sum_{k=a}^{b} {\rm E}g(k)\Delta f(k)$$

In short: the Abel summation is the discrete analog of

$$\int_a^b f(x)g'(x){\rm d}x=f(x)g(x)\Big|_a^b-\int_a^b f'(x)g(x){\rm d}x$$

---

Another way to memorizing the summation by parts formula its noticing that
$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{align*}
\enclose{circle}{1}&:\sum_{k=m}^{n}\Delta [f(k)g(k)]=f(n+1)g(n+1)-f(m)g(m)\\
\enclose{circle}{2}&:\Delta [f(k)g(k)]+f(k+1)g(k)-f(k+1)g(k)=f(k+1)\Delta g(k)+g(k)\Delta f(k)\\
\therefore\; & f(n+1)g(n+1)-f(m)g(m)=\sum_{k=m}^n f(k+1)\Delta g(k)+\sum_{k=m}^n g(k)\Delta f(k)
\end{align*}
$$

where this last expression is equivalent to the summation by parts formula.

Comment: Thanks. Can you briefly explain $$\sum_{k=a}^b f(k)=\sum\nolimits_a^{b+1} f(k)\delta k$$? I think this is one of the key points I don't understand.

Comment: @yoyostein Edited. Tell me if you dont understand something.

Comment: Looks good. I think I will have to read up more on finite calculus. I can get the overall idea though.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, understanding/proving/remembering this formula is especially easy when you refer to a graphical representation, as can be found for example in (http://mathbmt.com/sumofparts). Of course, there is a limitation at first to positive numbers, but this limitation can be overcome.

Comment: MathBMT is a nice site! Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, the link seems to have died.

Comment: Even though there is no picture, I found MathBMT's explanation helpful, which can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170103030852/mathbmt.com/sumofparts

Comment: @Jaspreet Thank you for having retrieved the thread !